# Pycharm keeps saying Name 'User' can be undefined

Tags: python

I was learning Json and Pycharm keeps warning me about `Name 'User' can be undefined` how do I get rid of this warning as it keeps bugging me the entire time

Here's my short Code:

```
import json

with open("Users.json") as f:
    data = json.load(f)


username = input("Enter Username:")
for users in data:
    User = users

if username == User:
    print(User)
    print("lol")
```

I'm still new to python

Comment: data must be empty

Comment: If `data` is empty, then User never receives a default value. Thus `Name 'User' can be undefined`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
import json

with open("Users.json") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

User = None

username = input("Enter Username:")
for users in data:
    User = users

if username == User:
    print(User)
    print("lol")
```

also, might I suggest adding the if statement inside the for loop like so:

```
import json

with open("Users.json") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

User = None

username = input("Enter Username:")
for users in data:
    User = users

    if username == User:
        print(User)
        print("lol")
```

Comment: This still has the same problem that the OP has: `User` *can* be undefined. Did you mean: `User = None`?

Comment: @quamrana yes that is what I meant. Thanks for pointing out the mistake!

Answer (score 1):

`User` won't be assigned when `data` is empty. You can initialize the variable with `None` to avoid the warning.